# Rock, Paper, Scissors 3-part

Tags: java, rock-paper-scissors

> Write a program that lets a user play "Rock,
>   Paper, Scissors" against the computer. The program should ask the user
>   to choose one of the three choices, and then the computer randomly
>   picks one (without knowing what the user has chosen). For this
>   problem, the user should be asked to enter an integer: 0 for rock, 1
>   for paper, or 2 for scissors. Rock beats scissors, scissors beats
>   paper, paper beats rock. The program should say who wins, and then
>   keep playing until someone (the user or the computer) has won 10
>   rounds. The computer needs to keep track of the current score and
>   should also display it before each round.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class rock_paper
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int count_win=0;
    int user_choice;
    String choice=" ";
    int num_comp_wins=0;
    int num_user_wins=0;
    while(num_comp_wins!=10||num_user_wins!=10)
    {
    /* Read user input and determine choice */

    System.out.println("\n Let us play Rock Paper Scissors \n");
    System.out.println("\n Enter your choice 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors \n");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    user_choice=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n Your choice was \n"+user_choice);
    if(user_choice==0)
    {
        choice="rock";
    }
    else if(user_choice==1)
    {
        choice="paper";
    }
    else if(user_choice==2)
    {
        choice="scissor";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect choice");
        choice=null;
    }
    System.out.println(choice);

    /* Randomly generate computer input */

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computer_choice = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    String choice1="";
    if(computer_choice==0)
    {
        choice1="rock";
    }
    else if(computer_choice==1)
    {
    choice1="paper";
    }
    else if(computer_choice==2)
    {
    choice1="scissor";
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect choice");
        choice1=null;
    }
    System.out.println(choice1);
   /* Compare user and computer response*/
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
    if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("scissor"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe user wins!");
        num_user_wins++;
    }
    else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe computer wins!");
        num_comp_wins++;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Tie");
}
else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
{
    if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("scissor"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe computer wins!");
        num_comp_wins++;
    }
    else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe user wins!");
        num_user_wins++;
    }
    else
         System.out.println("Tie");
}
else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissor"))
{
    if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe computer wins!");
        num_comp_wins++;
    }
    else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nThe user wins!");
        num_user_wins++;
    }
    else
         System.out.println("Tie");
}

}


}
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet? Have you learned about switch statements yet? That will help guide any answers.

Comment: Next: [Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Spock)? :-)

Answer (score 11):

### Naming

Java classes start with a capital letter and do not use underscores, so `rock_paper` should be `RockPaper`. Java uses camelCase, not snake_case, for all variable names except constants (`static final`s), so `user_choice` should be `userChoice`.

### Spacing

The convention in java is to include whitespace before and after operators such as +, =, != or ==, so `count_win=0` should be `countWin = 0`. Curly braces should be on the same line as an `if` or `else`.

### Variable Declarations

You declare a `new Random()` inside your loop, so you might wind up making 19 `Random` objects, when you only need one. Declare it outside the loop. Conversely, you declare `user_choice` and `computer_choice` outside the loop, but they're only used inside. They should have the smallest possible scope.

### Branching

You're branching (using `if` conditional statements) a lot to look up the name of a numeric selection. If you've learned about arrays, you could use a `String[]` of choices to simplify that lookup. There are a ton more branches to determine who wins. You only need one comparison to determine if there's a tie, and then only three specific checks to see if the user wins. Otherwise, the computer wins.

Making all those changes might look something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class RockPaperScissors {

    private static final String[] CHOICES = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };

    public static void main(final String[] argv) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int computerWins = 0;
        int userWins = 0;

        System.out.println("\n Let us play Rock Paper Scissors \n");
        while (computerWins <= 10 && userWins <= 10) {

            /* Read user input and determine choice */    
            System.out.println("\n Enter your choice 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors \n");
            final int userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 2) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect choice");
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n Your choice was \n" + CHOICES[userChoice]);
            }

            /* Randomly generate computer input */
            final int computerChoice = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
            System.out.println("\n The computer choice was \n" + CHOICES[computerChoice]);

            if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
                System.out.println("Tie");
                continue;
            }

            if (userChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 1
                    || userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2
                    || userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 0) {
                System.out.println("\nThe user wins!");
                userWins++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nThe computer wins!");
                computerWins++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Review Note: I intentionally don't close the `Scanner` because I'm assuming that hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: You could add a note that by using `continue` related to the incorrect choice, you are also avoiding a NULL exception which the OP has in the code. Good work!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest you use a two dimension array look up to determine the win lose matrix.

```
//-1 = user loses
// 0 = tie 
// 1 = user wins
int[][] winArray = new int[
            [0, -1, 1], 
            [1,  0,-1], 
            [-1, 1, 0]
      ]; 

int userMove;      //get from user input
int computerMove;  //randomly generated

int result = winArray[userMove, computerMove]
//now determine what happens if the user wins/loses/ties
```

Much simpler.